# How to change default port of a Rails 4 app?

Tags: port, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I know that I can start a rails server on another port via `-p` option. But I'd like to setup another port per application as long as I start webrick.

Any ideas?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Quick solution: Append to `Rakefile`

```
task :server do
  `bundle exec rails s -p 8080`
end
```

Then run `rake server`

Answer (score 36):

Append this to `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: 3001)
  end
end

Rails::Server.send(:prepend, DefaultOptions)
```

Note: ruby >= 2.0 required.

Comment: `prepend` is public, you don't need to go through `send`: `Rails::Server.prepend(DefaultOptions)`.

Comment: Not in recent versions no. Send is necessary: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Server.html

Comment: How do I retrieve this port from somewhere within the application?

Comment: Thanks, this works too when trying to change the default binding address :). Can you explain what does the code works?

Comment: I like this one because it allows me to run the server with `rails server` (as usual), rather than the chosen answer which requires a call to something else.

Comment: Actually nothing has been changed

Comment: @MadsBuus Recent versions of what? With Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.2.3 plain prepend works fine.

Comment: This stopped working for me in Rails 5.1. It had a good run though. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

#### Option 1:

You can launch WEBrick like so:

```
    rails server -p 8080
```

Where 8080 is your port. If you like, you can throw this in a bash script for convenience.

#### Option 2:

You could install `$ gem install foreman`, and use foreman to start your production webserver (e.g. unicorn) as defined in your `Procfile` like so: `$ foreman run web`. If unicorn is your web server you can specify the port in your unicorn config file (as with most server choices). The benefit of this approach is not only can you set the port in the config, but you're using an environment which is closer to production.

Answer (score 4):

**If you put the default options on `config/boot.rb` then all command attributes for rake and rails fails (example: `rake -T` or `rails g model user`)!** So, append this to `bin/rails` after line `require_relative '../config/boot'` and the code is executed only for the rails server command:

```
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `bin/rails` file loks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'

# Set default host and port to rails server
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: When you say "fails", what do you mean? It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 5.1:

```
# config/boot.rb

# ... existing code

require 'rails/command'
require 'rails/commands/server/server_command'

Rails::Command::ServerCommand.send(:remove_const, 'DEFAULT_PORT')
Rails::Command::ServerCommand.const_set('DEFAULT_PORT', 3333)
```