# what is the ruby on rails server port range and how to run the multiple ports using same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web, port

what is the ruby on rails server port range?

want to know the server port no range for ruby on rails . please guide me

how to run the multiple ports using same server?
want to run the same application in the different server port number like 3000 , 3005

Comment: `bundle exec rails server -p 3005`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default port of a Rails 4 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103316/how-to-change-default-port-of-a-rails-4-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The port range very much depends on the underlying operating system. It has nothing to do with Ruby or Rails.
- Do you want to run different instances with different port numbers or a single instance accessible from multiple ports? Either way you might want to look into setting up a proxy server in front of your instances (nginx can act as proxy for example).