# ActionMailer's default_url_options: How to retrieve port automatically from DefaultOptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I often have many Rails apps running in parallel, so I have configured them to use different ports:

```
# Change default port of development server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103316
require 'rails/commands/server'
module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: 3001)
  end
end
```

Now it's important that this also works for ActionMailer in development env:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3001'}
```

But instead of hardcoding this, I'd like to set it directly from `DefaultOptions`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small deviation from your code:

```
# config/boot.rb
require 'rails/commands/server'
module DefaultOptions
  PORT = 3001

  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: PORT)
  end
end

# This line was part of the Stack Overflow answer you quoted, and is important
# With newer Ruby versions, you can call `prepend` directly
Rails::Server.prepend(DefaultOptions)
```

This follows the Stack Overflow answer you quoted, with the exception of extracting the port to the constant `DefaultOptions::PORT`. Now note that there is nothing magical about the name of the module `DefaultOptions`, it simply defines a plain module that is then prepended to `Rails::Server`. You could have named it however you wanted. When the development server launches, a new `Rails::Server` object is instantiated, and at some point the `default_options` method is called on that object. Because of the use of `prepend`, the method lookup will first reach the method you defined in `DefaultOptions`. The `super` in that method simply calls the original un-prepended `default_options` defined in `Rails::Server`.

The reason why it is "hard" to get the values in `default_options` is because it is an instance method, meaning you can access it only on an instance of `Rails::Server` class, and we don't typically have a hold of the server object. You could access it like this:

```
# config/development.config
require 'rails/commands/server'
Rails::Server.new.default_options[:Port]
```

But I think this is an unnecessary dependency and object creation. The name `Rails::Server` also implies we may want to have just one object of this class, and I wouldn't instantiate server objects just to get a hold of their configuration hash. Therefore, extracting the port out to a constant you can hold regardless of whether you have a reference to a server object - `DefaultOptions::PORT` - is cleaner in my mind.

So, now that we got a hold of `DefaultOptions::PORT` constant, you can use it in your mailer:

```
# config/development.rb
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port => DefaultOptions::PORT,
  :address => '...',
  :user_name => '...',
  :password => '...',
  :domain => '...',
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

You could also consider having the mailer and port definition in a `yaml` file, so that you do not need to "sprinkle" parts of your configuration in different locations - it might save you some head banging later.

If you'd like to do this, you could create a wrapper class yourself that uses `YAML.load_file` to load your new `yaml` configuration file into a hash. Alternatively, check out `Figaro` gem, it gives a convenient way to place all Rails configurations in a single file - `application.yml` - and access them from everywhere using `ENV`.

If you were to use `Figaro`, for example, and have the `PORT` key in `application.yml`, then your code may look like this:

```
# config/boot.rb
require 'rails/commands/server'
module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: ENV['PORT'])
  end
end

Rails::Server.prepend(DefaultOptions)

# config/development.rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port => ENV['PORT'],
  :address => ENV['SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name => ENV['SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => ENV['MAILER_DOMAIN'],
  :authentication => :plain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rails::Server::Options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Server/Options.html) to get the information you need and then configure the ActionMailer accordingly:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Rails::Server.new.options[:Host], port: Rails::Server.new.options[:Port] }
```

Comment: This works when running `rails server`, but you will have check whether `Rails::Server` is defined because it won't be defined when running `rails c` for example.