# change localhost port number in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, react-rails, react-on-rails, port-number

I just started learning RoR as a backend technology for React. I came across a tutorial that uses 'react-rails' and it chooses the localhost port number to be 3000 for my development environment by default.

Is there any way to change this default port number?

Comment: check the `puma.rb` file in your config folder

Comment: Yep, thanks for that! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below mentioned link will help you regarding the port and address while running rails server

[Change my default localhost port in Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573775/change-my-default-localhost-port-in-rails-5).

Answer (score 1):

In development environment(local machine) you can not use port number below 1024

To start rails server on different port: -

```
rails s -p 5000 #or you can set your own port (> 1024)
```

Or to [start is on port 80 or less than 1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351844/how-to-run-rails-s-p80-on-80-port):-

```
rvmsudo rails server -p 80
```